# preg_match the end of two html tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I try to `preg_match` the end of two html tags

```
<span class="a"> 
   <span>123</span> 
   <span>456</span></span>
<span class="b">
    <span>789</span>
....
```

I want to get the content of class `a` (123 456) and try this pattern

```
preg_match('#<span\sclass="a">(.*?)</span></span>#')
```

but I just get the first span (123).

How can I end the pattern in `</span></span>`

Comment: You should use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead of using regex to parse HTML.

Comment: Do you want this http://phpio.net/s/336o ?

Answer (score 0):

[`<span class="a">([\W\w]*?)<\/span><\/span>`](https://regex101.com/r/BDpdXd/1)

The dot `.` only looks for non-newline characters, which means it would never get past the first line (in theory).